# last word of excerpt as a link

Tags: wordpress

Does anybody know how to do this ? I would like to use last word of post excerpt as a link to it (post). Just like in text below:

Curabitur porttitor sem quis ipsum rutrum pharetra. Aliquam molestie justo eget nibh vulputate placerat. Etiam aliquet augue [sit](http://google.com)

solved :)

```
function excerpt_read_more_link($output) {
 global $post;
 $output_array=explode (' ',$output);
 $count_words=count ($output_array);
 $last_word=$output_array[$count_words-1];
 for ($i=0; $i<$count_words-1;$i++)
 { $new_output.=$output_array[$i]." ";}
 return $new_output . '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">'.$last_word.'</a>';
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'excerpt_read_more_link');
```

Comment: check this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: I know that but  I was wondering how to recive last word of excerpt and then make it shorter. Then I could add it as `read more` link

for example: from 50 words to 49 and then add the 50th word at the end of shorter excerpt.

Comment: using `get_the_excerpt` filter. `add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt','your_function' );` in your function you will get the excerpt as a string you can get last word, and add anchor tag before and at end

Comment: Not so clean, but it works :)

 
   `function excerpt_read_more_link($output) {
     global $post;
     $output_array=explode (' ',$output);
     $count_words=count ($output_array);
     $last_word=$output_array[$count_words-1];
     for ($i=0; $i<$count_words-1;$i++)
     { $new_output.=$output_array[$i]." ";}
     return $new_output . '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">'.$last_word.'</a>';
    }
    add_filter('the_excerpt', 'excerpt_read_more_link');`